# Duda al insertar un elemento dentro de otro dentro de un bucle en Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto personal en `Vanilla JS` y tengo un problema en la siguiente función:

```
static displayRowsForActions(){
    let body = this.getBodyTable().children;
    let rows = document.createElement('td');
    let actions = `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
    rows.innerHTML = actions;
    Object.keys(body).map(value => {
        body[value].appendChild(rows);
    });
}
```

Bien, en la variable `body` recojo los `<tr>` que hay en una tabla `html`, a ello le quiero introducir los iconos que tengo en la variable `actions` en el bucle que tengo al final.

El problema viene a la hora de renderizar la tabla, pues sólo me pinta los iconos en el último `tr`.

Esto lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

```
static displayRowsForActions(){
    let body = this.getBodyTable().children;
    let actions = `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
    Object.keys(body).map(value => {
        let rows = document.createElement('td');
        rows.innerHTML = actions;
        body[value].appendChild(rows);
    });
}
```

Sin embargo, no me parece una solución correcta tener que crear una y otra vez el elemento en cada interacción del bucle, así como tampoco termino de comprender porque de la primera forma no me funciona como creo que debería.

¿Alguien me lo podría explicar? Gracias.

Comment: Hola arnold025, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo leer [ask], hacer el [tour] (y ganar así tu primera medalla), ¿podrías poner tu HTML también?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando obtienes un elemento en HTML o creas uno, lo que tienes en la variable que asignas, es la referencia a ESE elemento, es decir, solo es un elemento. En tu ejemplo, lo que haces es mover ese único elemento de un padre a otro. Por eso solo el ultimo tiene el elemento.

Como tu bien dices, no es buena idea estar creado elementos todo el rato, ya que esto ralentiza. Pero podemos clonar el elemento que ya tenemos:

```
static displayRowsForActions(){
    let body = this.getBodyTable().children;
    let rows = document.createElement('td');
    let actions = `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i><i class="fas fa-edit"></i><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
    rows.innerHTML = actions;
    Object.keys(body).map(value => {
        body[value].appendChild(rows.cloneNode(true));
    });
}
```

En este caso, el "true" indica que también clone toda la descendencia que tenga.